# Can i run a shell script through the spark-scala program?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, intellij-idea, apache-spark-sql

i'm writing a spark-scala program in intelligi, my code is basically to bring the table from oracle and store them in hdfs as text files `insert_df.rdd.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://path")`. I have tried this way, but it didn't work `val script_sh = "///samplepath/file_creation_script.sh".!`

But i have some conversions to make to the text file that I generated, I wrote a shell script to that. I dont want to run the spark jar file and the `.sh` file separately.

Please let me know if there is any way that i can call shell script through the program.

Comment: can you try `df.write.text("/hdfs/path")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to save the output of your command to a variable you need use:

```
import sys.process._
val result = "/path/to/your/script.sh".!! ("!" just execute the command)
```

And this can work like workaround:

```
import java.io.{BufferedReader, InputStreamReader}

  val p = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash","/path/to/your/script")
  val p2 = p.start()
  val br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p2.getInputStream()))

  var line:String = ""
  while ({line = br.readLine();  line!= null}) {
    println(line)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say try using spark APIs only.

Still if you want to trigger a shell script from spark  (1) and (2) worked for me

1. In client mode:

Just run the shell script from spark code

val cmd = "home/some_script.sh"

cmd!

2. In cluster mode:

I usually use Oozie , keep the .sh file in /lib folder of the workflow , this will copy the script to the containers.

from code invoke

val cmd = "./some_script.sh"

cmd!

For python "." wasnt required

val cmd = "python some_script.py"

cmd!

3. If using spark-submit Use --files to copy the script to containers .

Haven't tried 3 , one may try and share.